# How config "lerna add" to use ~ tilde instead of ^ caret?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, lerna

After run `lerna add` using command:

```
lerna add [module-1] \
  --scope [module-2] \
  --dev
```

My `package.json` of my `module-2` have the declaration of the dependency using "tilde":

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "components": "^0.0.0"
  }
}
```

My `yarn` and `npm` have the config `save-prefix` defined to use caret:

```
$ yarn config get save-prefix
~
```

Comment: Seems similar to  [issue #1157](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/1157) in the lerna repo.

Comment: Apparently not have a solution for this.